# Python I want to search a text document and find data that starts and end differently but might have different information inbetween

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to have python look at a text file, find data that matches and save that data to a new file. I would post my code, but it's not even close to working.

text file contents:

```
001  AX       V     C        00:59:56:09 01:00:56:09 00:58:30:00 00:59:30:00
* FROM CLIP NAME: Bars and Tone

002  BL       V     C        00:00:00:00 00:00:10:00 00:59:30:00 00:59:40:00

003  AX       V     C        00:59:56:09 01:00:06:09 00:59:40:00 00:59:50:00
* FROM CLIP NAME: SLATE Copy 02

004  BL       V     C        00:00:00:00 00:00:10:00 00:59:50:00 01:00:00:00

005  AX       V     C        00:59:56:09 01:00:01:09 01:00:00:00 01:00:05:00
* FROM CLIP NAME: Graphic

006  AX       V     C        01:00:00:00 01:01:15:08 01:00:05:00 01:01:20:08
* FROM CLIP NAME: OE100_ANIMATIC_MainTitle_NoOverlays.mp4

007  AX       V     C        00:00:00:00 00:00:02:13 01:01:20:08 01:01:22:21
* FROM CLIP NAME: OE101_10_113_t01_DR.mov

008  AX       V     C        00:00:00:00 00:00:06:15 01:01:22:21 01:01:29:12
* FROM CLIP NAME: OE101_10_114_t01_DR.mov

009  AX       V     C        00:00:00:00 00:00:04:16 01:01:29:12 01:01:35:06
* FROM CLIP NAME: OE101_10_114A_t01_DR.mov
M2   AX       019.6                      00:00:00:00 

010  AX       V     C        00:00:00:00 00:00:04:05 01:01:35:06 01:01:39:11
```

---

So I want to fine every time OExxxxxx.mov appears. This is what I am looking for...  OE101_10_113_t01_DR.mov

So anything that starts with OE and ends in .mov

Then I want it to take the found data and save it in a text file.

I don't need the answer, just point me in the right direction if you wouldn't mind.

Thank You!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: Doesn't matter if your code works. Ask about the part you're working on